# Why doesn't this survfit plot start at 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survival, ggfortify

When I plot the survfit plot of data with two different censoring events, the overall plot (s0) doesnt start at time = 0, pstate = 100%, but jumps to 100% when the first cencoring event occurs.

[image: Jumping survival fit]

Here you can see in an example, where the jump occurs at time 1, that is the first cencoring event.

```
library(survival)
library(ggfortify)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1337)

dummy_data = tibble(time = sample.int(100, 100, replace = TRUE),
                    event = sample.int(3, 100, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(event = factor(event))

kaplanMeier <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data=dummy_data)
autoplot(kaplanMeier, facets = TRUE)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in `ggfortify:::fortify.survfit`.  The web page for the package is here:  https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify; maybe someone there can suggest a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem to be a bug in ggfortify. As a temporary fix, you can set the survival percentage at t = 0 to 100% by doing:

```r
p <- autoplot(kaplanMeier, facets = TRUE)

p$layers[[1]]$data[1, c(5, 7, 8)] <- 1
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Since in my original code, I used different strata, I adapted your workaround to this `  p$layers[[1]]$data$pstate[p$layers[[1]]$data$time == 0 & p$layers[[1]]$data$event == "(s0)"] = 1
  p$layers[[1]]$data$lower[p$layers[[1]]$data$time == 0 & p$layers[[1]]$data$event == "(s0)"] = 1
  p$layers[[1]]$data$upper[p$layers[[1]]$data$time == 0 & p$layers[[1]]$data$event == "(s0)"] = 1`
It's not as short as your solution, though.